# How to separate super class object from base class object?

Tags: java, inheritance, superclass

I have two classes, class A and Class B.

```
class A {

  String abcd;
  String efgh;
}

class B extends A {

  String check1;
  String check2;
}
```

I'm having one object of class B in one other class. I want to get a separate object of class A from the subclass B. Is there any special methods in java for separating these two classes? Please Help me to get the proper answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "separating" these classes? Refactor inheritance?

Comment: Are you talking about casting `B` to `A` ?

Comment: actually i need the object of class A from Class B

Comment: @JijeshKumar it still doesn't make much sense to me. Are you trying to initialize an instance of `A` in `B`? Are you referring to `super`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm having one object of class B in one other class. I want to get a separate object of class A from the subclass B.

There is only **one** object, not two.

> Is there any special methods in java for separating these two classes?

No, because again, there is only *one* object.

There are typically two ways you'd get at *just* the `A` aspects of a `B` instance:

1. Create a *copy* of just the `A` aspects of the object, usually using a copy constructor in `A`. This creates a new, second object which copies the aspects of the instance that are specific to `A`. If `A` doesn't have a copy constructor that's suitable, you'd have to add one (if you can modify `A`) or create your own method to do it (if possible, some classes have state they don't expose).

   For example, here's `A` with a copy constructor:

   ```
   class A {

     String abcd;
     String efgh;

     public A(A a) {
       this.abcd = a.abcd;
       this.efgh = a.efgh;
     }
   }
   ```

   Then if you have a `B` instance:

   ```
   B b = new B();
   ```

   ...you'd use the copy constructor to **copy** the `A` aspects of that to a second object:

   ```
   A a = new A(b);
   ```
2. If you just want a reference to the existing object that's of type `A` rather than `B`, you just do an assignment:

   ```
   B b = new B();
   A a = b;
   ```

   There's still *only one object*, and it's still a `B` object, but the `a` variable only gives access to the properties and methods defined for `A`.

I suspect you probably want the copy constructor, but I figured I should mention the other in case you were just trying to hide some of the `B` capabilities from part of the code (which isn't uncommon).

Answer (score 0):

There is only one object (of child class). Print `this` and check.

**actually i need the object of class A from Class B**

This isn't *composition*, extending classes implies *inheritance*, you won't have class A instance inside class B instance.

Answer (score 0):

`classBObject.getClass().getSuperclass()` will return you the parent class of `Class B`.

Comment: i need the instance of super class

Answer (score 0):

> I'm having one object of class B in one other class. I want to get a separate object of class A from the subclass B.

in the design you provided, you actually have only one object **B** that inherits from **A**, so the relationship between the two objects is "[is a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a)" relationship. In case of this relationship, you cannot separate the two classes. In case of composition, ("[has-a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a)" relationship) you could get encapsulated object, a naive implementation of the second relationship would look like this:

```
 class A {
  String abcd;
  String efgh;
 }

 class B {
   String check1;
   String check2;
   A a;

   A getA() {
      return a;
   }
}
```